# How to show empty view reliably for RecyclerView only when RealmResults is empty

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I understand there are a lot of information about it out there, but I haven't found one that matches my case yet.

I have a recycleview on a fragment that is always open, so the fragment basically never re-creates itself.

This is my code to load the adapter.

```
    reLoad(); //method shown below
    mRecycler.setAdapter(new SolicitationAdapter(myRealm.where(SolicitationDatabase.class).findAllAsync()));
```

And this is the logic I came up with:

```
public void reLoad() {
    if (!myRealm.where(SolicitationDatabase.class).findAll().isEmpty()) {
        mNothingHere.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mNothingHere.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

It works great the first time the user opens the app.

The trouble starts when the user creates a record, since the fragment doesn't re-create itself it never reloads.

The reason I haven't been able to reload after user adds something is because the method to add a **new record is on a singleton being called from a different activity**. Which means when I try to do it I get a nullpointerexception when declaring the the recycleview and the textview.

## Edit - What I tried (reloading views from another place)

I have a class called PostHelper, this class is in charge of posting a new record.

This is the constructor:

```
public PostHelper(Context context, Activity activity) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mActivity = activity; //I call this in order to use "findViewById"
```

This is where the post happens:

```
public String addSolicitation(File _file, boolean fromQueue) {
//loading view
    TextView nothingHere = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.nothing_here);
    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
...so on until after the post:
SolicitationAdapter n = new SolicitationAdapter(myRealm.where(SolicitationDatabase.class).findAll());
n.notifyDataSetChanged();

nothingHere.setVisibility(View.GONE);
recycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
06-01 21:43:37.511 9122-9122/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.ga.realm3, PID: 9122
                                             io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

## Edit 2 - I load PostHelper class using the following:

```
mPostHelper = new PostHelper(this, PostSolicitationActivity.this);
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace and the other code

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it with the required information. Would you please help me?

Comment: If you are updating Realm "from a different activity", then you should not pass a whole reference of another activity there... Plus, an Activity is a context, so you just duplicated parameters... I can't really follow the code you added, otherwise, but calling `findViewById` doesn't work like that. Have you tried only passing the TextView & RecyclerView? Assuming you really need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to make sure that `SolicitationAdapter` is a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, like so:

```
public class SolicitationAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<SolicitationDatabase, SolicitationViewHolder> {
     public SolicitationAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<SolicitationDatabase> results) {
         super(results, true);
     }
 ...
}
```

And then what you need to do is that you put the RealmResults as a field reference in your Activity:

```
public class PostSoliticiationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     RealmResults<Solicitation> results;
     Realm realm;
     RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Solicitiation> realmChangeListener = (results) -> {
         if(results.isLoaded() && results.isValid()) {
            if(results.isEmpty()) {
                mNothingHere.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mNothingHere.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
         }
     }

     SolicitationAdapter adapter;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
         super.onCreate(bundle);
         setContentView(R.layout.soliticiation_activity);
         // bind views 
         realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
         results = realm.where(SolicitationDatabase.class).findAllSortedAsync("id");
                                // .sort("id").findAllAsync(); in 4.3.0+
         results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
         adapter = new SoliticiationAdapter(results);
         mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
         // layout manager as well
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
         realm.close();
         super.onDestroy();
     }
}
```

---

So things you don't need:

1.) `reLoad()` method

2.) `onPostAdded` callback

3.) `PostActionListener`

As long as you just add the `SoliticiationDatabase` to the Realm in a transaction, it'll all work without manually syncing ui.

Comment: I'm about to test it, by the way, the adapter is actually out of your own doing (Realm book by example)! You're always helping me out, I really appreciate that.

Comment: It's a sound strategy. However, the only thing keeping it from working is that I can't bind the views on PostSolicitationActivity. They belong to HistoryFragment. [Stacktrace here](https://gist.github.com/madd86/9fea4cf7981e81da1e0f84141cdd4775)

Comment: Nevermind did it on HistoryFragment and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be notified in another view when an action happens elsewhere.

The way to do that is usually interfaces.

```
public class PostHelper {

    // Define these
    public interface PostActionListener {
        void onPostAdded();
    }

    private PostActionListener postListener;

    public void setPostActionListener(PostActionListener listener) throws ClassCastException {
        this.postListener = (PostActionListener) context;
    }

    public PostHelper(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

        // Cast the passed context as a listener
        if (mContext instanceof PostActionListener) {
            this.postListener = (PostActionListener) mContext;
        }
    }

    public String addSolicitation(File _file, boolean fromQueue) {
        // Do something

        // Callback to the UI to update
        if (this.postListener != null) {
            this.postListener.onPostAdded();
        }
    }
```

Then, in your initial Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements PostHandler.PostActionListener {

    // ... fields

    @Override
    public void onPostAdded() {
        reLoad();
    }

    public void reLoad() {
        boolean emptyList = myRealm.where(SolicitationDatabase.class).findAll().isEmpty();
        mNothingHere.setVisibility(emptyList ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mRecycler.setVisibility(emptyList ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        ...

        mPostHelper = new PostHelper(this);
    }
```

**However**, since you are using Realm, and there really is no data that you need to "return" here, then you can simply let the Android Activity lifecycle refresh the data for you.

Comment: Well, I added the disclaimer at the bottom :) I essentially manually implement the `RealmChangeListener`